# Simplify react state update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a simple react application and I want to update the state of a component based on certain conditions. Currently, I'm using a hardcoded solution that works, but it seems too complicated and I want to know if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      value: 'initial'
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      if (prevState.count === 0) {
        return { count: prevState.count + 1, value: 'clicked once' };
      } else if (prevState.count === 1) {
        return { count: prevState.count + 1, value: 'clicked twice' };
      } else {
        return { count: prevState.count + 1, value: 'clicked many times' };
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This works, but it's not scalable and becomes hard to manage as the number of conditions increases.

Comment: I suggest you look into hooks, class components are basically history now, function components are so much easier to use.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie "use hooks" isn't the solution. see my answer for explanation.

Comment: @Mulan Indeed, it's a comment, that's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing stress because your `value` state is an anti-pattern. It is a derivative of `count` and should not have state of its own. That is to say `count` is your [single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned) -

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const onClick = event => setCount(c => c + 1)
  return <div>
    <button onClick={onClick} children="click" />
    <p>
      { count == 0 
      ? "initial" // derived from count
      : count == 1
      ? "clicked once"
      : count == 2
      ? "clicked twice"
      : "clicked many times"
      }
    </p>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

As a class-based component, that might look like this -

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 }
  onClick = e =>  this.setState(s => ({ count: s.count + 1 }))
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.onClick} children="click" />
      <p>
        { this.state.count == 0 // derived from count
        ? "initial"
        : this.state.count == 1
        ? "clicked once"
        : this.state.count == 2
        ? "clicked twice"
        : "clicked many times"
        }
      </p>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional operator.

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count + 1, value: 
'clicked ' + (prevState.count === 0 ? 'once' : prevState.count === 1 ? 'twice' : 'many times')}));
```